# How to draw a vertical line on HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I want to trace a vertical time line on the current day, but I didn't found solution on HighCharts documentation.

Like this :

[image]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're looking for a plot line. See the documentation here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.

The basic format is:

```
xAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        color: '#FF0000', // Red
        width: 2,
        value: 5.5 // Position, you'll have to translate this to the values on your x axis
    }]
},
```

Comment: Is there a way to add/remove plot lines dynamically? xAxis[0].addPlotLine({ color: 'red', width: 1, value: <variable> }) adds the plotline but it gets accumulated