# Drawing a small vertical line on top of chart using High charts by specifying end coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am new to High Charts for drawing charts. My requirement is to draw a small vertical line on top of already drawn chart by specifying end coordinates. I can easily draw one using the JqPlot plugin and the image is given below.

[image]

The options I have used in JqPlot is

```
canvasOverlay: {
                    show: true,
                    objects: [
                        {line: {
                                name: 'stack-overflow',                                    
                                lineWidth: 6,
                                start: [8, 0.5],
                                stop:[8, 0.7],
                                color: 'rgb(100, 55, 124)',
                                shadow: false
                            }}
                    ]
                }
```

On some research I have found that I can use **plotLines** in High charts

[Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427943/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-on-highcharts)

I have tried this option but it draws a full length red vertical line and I don't see any option to restrict the length of the line.

[image]

The code I have used is given below

```
 xAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 35,
                    tickInterval: 5,
                    title: {text: "Time"},
                    plotLines: [{
                            color: 'red',
                            width: 5,
                            value: 5.5
                        }]

                }
```

UPDATE:

JSFiddle link is given below

[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7p04marb/)

Am I missing something or do I need to try some other options

Comment: Can you create a DEMO of your code?

Comment: @RahulGupta I added the fiddle in question

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Highcharts renderer` option

```
function (chart) {
    var lineStartXposition2 = lineStartXposition + chart.plotLeft + 10,
        lineStartYposition2 = lineStartYposition + chart.plotTop + 10,
        lineEndXposition2 = lineEndXposition + chart.plotLeft + 10,
        lineEndYposition2 = lineEndYposition + chart.plotTop + 10;

    chart.renderer.path(['M', positionX, positionY, 'L', positionX, positionEnd])
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add();
});
```

**Update 3 : New fiddle using point coordinates and variables**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/db4m36rj/)

Comment: Thanks. But can I use X-Y coordinates instead of ['M', 210, 80, 'L', 210, 130]

Comment: This array use X-y Coordonates

Comment: But looking into the fiddle, Red Line coordinates should be (12,70) and (12,90) instead of (210,80) and (210,130)

Comment: @KiranMuralee look the new fiddle. it use point coordinate but I din't look to recalculate on window.resize.

Comment: Please look into example given for JqPlot in question, the line is drawn by specifying coordinates  start: [8, 0.5], stop:[8, 0.7] and it draws exactly the line bound by coordinates, but when I give the code as chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 0, 'L', 0, 100]), the (0,0) position is top left corner not the (0,0) position in graph.I hope you understand my point. Look at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7p04marb/3/

Comment: That why I update my answer to calculate good coordinates to show near the selected point `chart.series[1].data[1]`. Change the point near where you want to see the line appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163045/discussion-between-kiran-muralee-and-core972).

Comment: @KiranMuralee this update now use variable like you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following link will help you

```
    chart.addSeries({ 
    name: 'Line Marker Values',
    type:'scatter',
    marker: {
        symbol:'hline',
        lineWidth:2,
        lineColor:'rgba(253,0,154,0.9)',
        radius:12
    },
    data: [32,35,37,28,42,35,27]
});
```

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/m85yv3aq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use appropriately configured scatter series for this.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
  }, {
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: null // don't dispaly tooltip
    },
    states: {
        hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    type: 'scatter', // points don't need to be sorted
    lineWidth: 3,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    showInLegend: false,
    data: [
      [2, 3], [2, 5]
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/gab2ow7f/